# Extracting the column name from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two schemas, say 'DB_Internals and 'Network'.

Both the schemas contain a table called cable. I just want to extract column names alone from the table 'cable' in both the schemas and check whether any difference in column names using SQL.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you explain it in brief that what your need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In DB_Internals schema,rename the table name to cable_1

Give grants to table 'Cable_1' to 'Network' schema..

```
grant select on cable_1 to network;
```

Now, login to Network schema..

```
select column_name from dba_tab_columns where table_name='cable'
minus
select COLUMN_NAME from dba_tab_columns where table_name='cable_1';
```

Comment: Thankyou it works fine.Will the expression be same in case of postgresql too?

Comment: That looks like Oracle. It won't run in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The data needed for your query is in the information schema:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html

You then need to compare the two tables using that data. Options to do so are plenty, e.g.:

- list1 full join list2 with one or the other is null
- (list1 except list2) union all (list2 except list1)
- list columns of both group by column_name having count(*) <> 2
- etc.